# using dynamic textbox to add lot of data into table on same id

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have a table whose column names are h1 to h40. I am using dynamic text box method. According to my image i will enter data in textbox will save it with save button and with + sign I will add new text box. On submitting first data it will be inserted  to h1 and on adding second textbox h2 to h40 will be updated. but I am not getting success. How to achieve it?

```
if (isset($_POST['save'])) {
    $n = $_POST['textbox'];
    echo $n;
    $query = mysqli_query($bd, "INSERT INTO col_heading1(h1) VALUES('$n')") or die("error in $query == ----> " . mysqli_error($bd));
    $lastid = mysqli_insert_id($bd);
    header('location:column.php');
} //echo $lastid; if(isset($_POST['update'])) { $n= $_POST['textbox']; echo $n; $query = mysqli_query($bd,"UPDATE col_heading1 SET h2='$n'") or die("error in $query == ----> ".mysqli_error($bd)); header('location:column.php'); } ?>
```

Comment: Please include all relevant code.

Comment: if(isset($_POST['save']))
 {
 $n= $_POST['textbox'];
 echo $n;
 $query =  mysqli_query($bd,"INSERT INTO col_heading1(h1) VALUES('$n')") or die("error in $query == ----> ".mysqli_error($bd));
 $lastid = mysqli_insert_id($bd);
header('location:column.php');
 }
 //echo $lastid;
 if(isset($_POST['update']))
 {
  $n= $_POST['textbox'];
  echo $n;
  
  $query = mysqli_query($bd,"UPDATE col_heading1 SET h2='$n'") or die("error in $query == ----> ".mysqli_error($bd));
  header('location:column.php');
  
  }

 ?>

Comment: Don't push the code as a comment, just edit your post and include it there

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to insert dynamic textbox data in a table with undefined number of values on same id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44020288/how-to-insert-dynamic-textbox-data-in-a-table-with-undefined-number-of-values-on)   whcih is asked by you

Comment: Your colomn names h1, h2 .. are not dynamically changing.

Comment: how to change them dynamically